# Best algorithm for netting orders

Tags: algorithm

I am building a marketplace, and I want to build a matching mechanism for market participants orders.

For instance I receive these orders:

```
A buys 50
B buys 100
C sells 50
D sells 20
```

that can be represented as a `List<Orders>`, where `Order` is a class with `Participant`,`BuySell`, and `Amount`

I want to create a `Match` function, that outputs 2 things:

1. A set of unmatched orders (`List<Order>`)
2. A set of matched orders (`List<MatchedOrder>` where `MatchOrder` has `Buyer`,`Seller`,`Amount`

The constrain is to minimize the number of orders (unmatched and matched), while leaving no possible match undone (ie, in the end there can only be either buy or sell orders that are unmatched)

So in the example above the result would be:

```
A buys 50 from C
B buys 20 from D
B buys 80 (outstanding)
```

This seems like a fairly complex algorithm to write but very common in practice. Any pointers for where to look at?

Comment: you may wanna consider network flow algorithms

Comment: @Mox: thanks I'll take a look. At first sight though it seems that flow algorithms are solving a very general case of the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Are you not required to honour the principle of first in, first served?  If you aren't, then it means that another order arriving can arbitrarily change the matching of previous buy and sell orders, so that e.g. a buy order that was previously matched with a sell order now reverts to being outstanding.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: no I'm not required, it's a once a day kind of thing, and the time of day is not taken into account in the algorithm.

Comment: I have solved this exact issue using a genetic algorithm implementation, but I cannot vouch for its performance, nor could I say that the final solution given was guaranteed to be the 100% best. The algorithm would produce a reasonable "best" after about 10 minutes on a sizable input, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can model this as a flow problem in a bipartite graph. Every selling node will be on the left, and every buying node will be on the right. Like this:

[image: graphviz]]

Then you must find the maximum amount of flow you can pass from `source` to `sink`.

You can use any maximum flow algorithms you want, e.g. [Ford Fulkerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm). To minimize the number of orders, you can use a Maximum Flow/Min Cost algorithm. There are a number of techniques to do that, including applying Cycle Canceling after finding a normal MaxFlow solution.

After running the algorithm, you'll probably have a residual network like the following:

[image]

Comment: But I don't think this is minimizing the *number* of flows, it is just finding one answer that works. am I right?

Comment: @d--b You're right, didn't pay attention to that. But you can still solve it with this modelling, you just have to use a MaxFlow/MinCost algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `WithRemainingQuantity` structure with 2 members:  a pointeur `o` to an order and an integer to store the unmatched quantity
2. Consider 2 `List<WithRemainingQuantity>` , 1 for buys Bq, 1 for sells Sq, both sorted by descending quantities of the contained order.
3. the algo match the head of each queue until one of them is empty

Algo (mix of meta and c++) :

```
struct WithRemainingQuantity
{
    Order * o;
    int remainingQty; // initialised with o->getQty
}


struct MatchedOrder
{
    Order * orderBuy;
    Order * orderSell;
    int matchedQty=0;
}

List<WithRemainingQuantity> Bq;
List<WithRemainingQuantity> Sq;

/*
populate Bq and Sq and sort by quantities descending, 
this is what guarantees the minimum of matched.
*/    

List<MatchedOrder> l;
while( ! Bq.empty && !Sq.empty)
{
    int matchedQty = std::min(Bq.front().remainingQty, Sq.front().remainingQty)

    l.push_back( MatchedOrder(orderBuy=Bq.front(), sellOrder=Sq.front(), qtyMatched=matchedQty) )

    Bq.remainingQty -= matchedQty
    Sq.remainingQty -= matchedQty

    if(Bq.remainingQty==0)
        Bq.pop_front()

    if(Sq.remainingQty==0)
        Sq.pop_front()
}
```

The unmatched orders are the remaining orders in Bq or Sq (one of them if fatally empty, according to the `while` clause).

Comment: I don't think this is correct, the problem is more complex than just matching with a stack. You are not guaranteed you're getting the optimal answer here.

Comment: yes it is because the list are sorted by quantities. Your objectif function (constraint) is not clear but you can tune the sorting criterion (sellers ascending, buyers descending for example). I am using this approch in my trading company in back office ...

Comment: could you give details on the constraints ?

Comment: the objective is to always find the minimum number of (trades + outstanding order). Sorting is not enough to ensure this.